# 301 Redirect is Not Working with Index File

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to 301 Redirect the `Index.php` to another URL

Here's my htaccess codes

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 /index.php /en1

RewriteRule en1 index.php [NC]
```

My domain for example is

```
www.mysite.com
```

I want this to work as

```
www.mysite.com/en1
```

In the URL bar its showing the new URL but browser says

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly
```

How to fix this 301 Redirect?

Comment: Thanks for showing you code/rules. Please do add sample of URLs like: **from** which url **to** which url you want to redirect in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: I have edited my question with URL example

Comment: Ok sure, I have added an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine ON

##Implement http ---> https rules here.
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

##External redirect rules here.
RewriteRule ^/?$ /en5 [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to index.php rules here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en5/?$ index.php [L]
```

***OR*** If you want to write a Generic rule for rewriting each non-existing file to index.php then try following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine ON

##Implement http ---> https rules here.
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

##External redirect rules here.
RewriteRule ^/?$ /en5 [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite to index.php rules here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

***NOTE:*** Use either of rules set one at a time only.

Comment: thanks a lot @RavinderSingh13 Its now working as expected

Comment: Its working fine but when I check the Redirect its showing `https://mysite .com` to `http://mysite .com` its removing `https` while redirecting.

Comment: @K.Mughal, oh ok, in case you have rules to apply http ----> https then put them at top  of thsse new rules(mine ones) and below RewriteEngine ON and it should work fine then. Check it once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Its not working actually I'm using cloudflare as `https` any other suggestion?

Comment: @K.Mughal, you don't have https rules with you in your .htaccess? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: I'm using something like this 

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?$ /en5 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en5/?$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: @K.Mughal, yeah I was saying the samething, I have edited the rules now, kindly do check them once and let me know then, cheers.

Comment: No brother none of them is working its still redirecting from `https` to `http`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248893/discussion-between-k-mughal-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @K.Mughal, I am sorry I can't join chat, please do comment in comments section here.

Comment: ok the problem solved by installing end to end SSL certificate from cloudflare to my host thanks for your great time @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @K.Mughal, ahhh ha great to hear, cheers and happy learning. Keep posting Good Q & A on this great site, cheers.